# How to count the number of items of a parent array by its child array object property

Tags: javascript, arrays

Supposed i have an array of personnel which has many offices.

```
var personnel = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John Doe',
    offices: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Office 1',
        isAssigned: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Office 2',
        isAssigned: true
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Office 3',
        isAssigned: false
      }
    ]
  },{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jerry Smith',
    offices: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Office 2',
        isAssigned: true,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Office 3',
        isAssigned: false,
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can i get the count of the personnel which is assigned in a particular office? Or how many is assigned in `office 2`? Result: `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
const office2Personnel = personnel.filter(p =>
        p.offices.some(o => o.name === 'Office 2' && o.isAssigned));

console.log(office2Personnel.length);
```

```js
const personnel = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John Doe',
    offices: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Office 1',
        isAssigned: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Office 2',
        isAssigned: true
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Office 3',
        isAssigned: false
      }
    ]
  },{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jerry Smith',
    offices: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Office 2',
        isAssigned: true,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Office 3',
        isAssigned: false,
      }
    ]
  }
];

const office2Personnel = personnel.filter(p => p.offices.some(o => o.name === 'Office 2' && o.isAssigned));

console.log(office2Personnel.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here a version that destructures the arguments:

```
personnel.filter( ({offices}) => 
    offices.some( ({name, isAssigned}) => isAssigned && name === office) 
).length
```

```js
function countInOffice(personnel, office) {
    return personnel.filter( ({offices}) => 
        offices.some( ({name, isAssigned}) => isAssigned && name === office) 
    ).length
}

var personnel = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John Doe',
    offices: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Office 1',
        isAssigned: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Office 2',
        isAssigned: true
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Office 3',
        isAssigned: false
      }
    ]
  },{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jerry Smith',
    offices: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Office 2',
        isAssigned: true,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Office 3',
        isAssigned: false,
      }
    ]
  }
];

var count = countInOffice(personnel, 'Office 2');

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over the assigned offices and adding the count to an object

This will get a count for each office

```js
var personnel = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'John Doe',
  offices: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Office 1',
      isAssigned: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Office 2',
      isAssigned: true
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Office 3',
      isAssigned: false
    }
  ]
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Jerry Smith',
  offices: [{
      id: 2,
      name: 'Office 2',
      isAssigned: true,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Office 3',
      isAssigned: false,
    }
  ]
}];

let offices = {};
personnel.forEach(p=>{
  p.offices.filter(o=>o.isAssigned).forEach(o=>{
    offices[o.name] = offices[o.name] || 0;
    offices[o.name]++;
  });
});

console.log(offices);
let officeToCheck = "Office 2";
console.log(offices[officeToCheck]);
```

If you need to directly get the count for a specific office

```js
var personnel = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'John Doe',
  offices: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Office 1',
      isAssigned: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Office 2',
      isAssigned: true
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Office 3',
      isAssigned: false
    }
  ]
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Jerry Smith',
  offices: [{
      id: 2,
      name: 'Office 2',
      isAssigned: true,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Office 3',
      isAssigned: false,
    }
  ]
}];

let count = personnel.filter(p=>p.offices.some(o=>o.name==='Office 2'&&o.isAssigned)).length;
console.log(count);
```

Comment: thanks for the response but arent that it just counting the number of `isAssigned = true`?

Comment: It is counting the number of `isAssigned=true` for each offices

Answer (score 1):

To get total counts(statistics for all *offices*: *"how many employees are assigned to each office"*) use the following approach:

```js
var personnel = [{id: 1,name: 'John Doe',offices: [{id: 1,name: 'Office 1',isAssigned: false},{id: 2,name: 'Office 2',isAssigned: true},{id: 3,name: 'Office 3',isAssigned: false}]},{id: 2,name: 'Jerry Smith',offices: [{id: 2,name: 'Office 2',isAssigned: true,},{id: 3,name: 'Office 3',isAssigned: false,}]}
],

    counts = personnel.reduce(function (r, o) {
        o.offices.forEach(function (i) {
            (r[i.name])? ++r[i.name] : r[i.name] = 1;
        });
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(counts);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use two nested [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and check for the given name.

```js
function getCount(name) {
    return personnel.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return a.offices.reduce(function (s, b) {
            return s + (b.name === name);
        }, r);
    }, 0);
}

var personnel = [{ id: 1, name: 'John Doe', offices: [{ id: 1, name: 'Office 1', isAssigned: false }, { id: 2, name: 'Office 2', isAssigned: true }, { id: 3, name: 'Office 3', isAssigned: false }] }, { id: 2, name: 'Jerry Smith', offices: [{ id: 2, name: 'Office 2', isAssigned: true, }, { id: 3, name: 'Office 3', isAssigned: false, }] }],
    result = getCount('Office 2');

console.log(result);
```

If you have only one single name in one office, you could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and exit if one name is found.

```js
function getCount(name) {
    return personnel.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r + a.offices.some(function (b) {
            return b.name === name;
        });
    }, 0);
}

var personnel = [{ id: 1, name: 'John Doe', offices: [{ id: 1, name: 'Office 1', isAssigned: false }, { id: 2, name: 'Office 2', isAssigned: true }, { id: 3, name: 'Office 3', isAssigned: false }] }, { id: 2, name: 'Jerry Smith', offices: [{ id: 2, name: 'Office 2', isAssigned: true, }, { id: 3, name: 'Office 3', isAssigned: false, }] }],
    result = getCount('Office 2');

console.log(result);
```

ES6

```js
function getCount(name) {
    return personnel.reduce((r, a) =>  r + a.offices.some(b => b.name === name), 0);
}

var personnel = [{ id: 1, name: 'John Doe', offices: [{ id: 1, name: 'Office 1', isAssigned: false }, { id: 2, name: 'Office 2', isAssigned: true }, { id: 3, name: 'Office 3', isAssigned: false }] }, { id: 2, name: 'Jerry Smith', offices: [{ id: 2, name: 'Office 2', isAssigned: true, }, { id: 3, name: 'Office 3', isAssigned: false, }] }],
    result = getCount('Office 2');

console.log(result);
```